# Recursivley Test if a Binary Search Tree is complete

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

A few days ago I asked a question about this same project, since then our group has managed to complete all of our methods except one that is used to determine if a binary search tree is complete.

We are using a wrapper method and a helper method to recursively do so.

We know that we need to check up to level h-1 of the tree (h is height) to make sure it is perfect, then we need to make sure all the leaf nodes on the final level are going from left to right with no gaps.

No matter what we try we can not figure out how to recursively check the remaining leaf nodes to make sure they are as consecutive from left to right. We are able to make sure that it is perfect up to level (h-1) however.

Could someone point us in the right direction on how to recursively check the leaf nodes on  the last level to make sure they are left aligned?

so far this is are code?

```
public boolean isComplete() 
{
    if (isPerfect(root))
        return true;    
    return isComplete(root);

}
/**
 * 
 * @param node
 * @return 
 */
private boolean isComplete(Node node)
{  
   if (height(node) > 1)
   {
   if (node.left != null && node.right != null && (height(node.left) == height(node.right)))
       return isComplete(node.left) && isComplete(node.right);
   else
       return false;
   }

}
```

P.S all trivial cases are handled in the isPerfect() method since every perfect tree is also complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to communicate with my professor, and he informed mof an O(n) way of doing it with only one parameter in the isComplete method, compared to some answers given here.

this answer here is the best answer for my original question

1. if hR > hL the tree is not complete.
2. if hL - HR > 1, the tree is not complete.
3. if hR == hL, then the left subtree must be perfect and the right subtree must be complete
4. otherwise (hL - hR == 1), then the left
   subtree must be perfect and the right subtree
   must be perfect.

steps 3 and 4 must recursively check if the tree isPerfect() and isComplete()

Answer (score 0):

I will try to first note the algorithm to check for completeness, and then move on to the code.

Let us think of this in a pre-order traversal approach.

- need the number of nodes in the tree
- recurse from the root, treating root as node index 0
- if node is null, tree is complete
- if node index is greater than (or equal to) the number of nodes in the tree, then it is not complete
- recurse on left and right subtree; given the pre-order traversal approach, left tree gets index `2*i + 1` and right tree gets `2*i + 2`.

A bit of an understanding into why this should work.

The following is a complete tree *[with node indices in square brackets]*. **Note that the node indices in case of this complete binary tree are strictly less be than the number of nodes in the complete binary tree**.

```
          1 [0]
         / \
        /   \
   [1] 2     3 [2]
      / \
     /   \
[3] 4     5 [4]
```

A function to return the total number of nodes in the tree

```
private int totalNodes(Node root) {
    if (root == null) 
        return 0;

    return 1 + totalNodes(root.left) + totalNodes(root.right));
}
```

Now, the wrapper isComplete() function **[with 0 parameters, since the root will be a class field]**...

```
public boolean isComplete() {
    return isCompleteHelper(root, 0, totalNodes(root));
}
```

The isCompleteHelper()...

```
private booelan isCompleteHelper(Node root, int indx, int totalNodes) {

    // empty tree 
    if (root == null)        
       return true;

    // present index >= number of nodes in tree
    if (indx >= totalNodes)
       return false;

    // recurse
    return isCompleteHelper(root.left, 2*indx+1, totalNodes) && isCompleteHelper(root.right, 2*indx+2, totalNodes);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested or run or compiled this. So, please be wary of minor bugs

Comment: while your code may work, it deviates from the requirements  of using only one parameter in the wrapper method. Thank you for the input though! I can probably use the steps you gave to conjure something up.

Comment: @sbowde4  I don't know if you noticed, the wrapper does use only one parameter

Comment: the wrapper method shouldn't use a parameter and the helper should is what I mean. Only one node parameter is allowed

Comment: @sbowde4 Well, yea. I made an edit. Since, `root` is a class field, `isComplete()` wrapper will obviously not need it as a parameter. Given this approach, the helper needs 3 params, and that cannot change. Otherwise, you can use the height to test for completeness, which is also pretty elementary.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now,  I have to check the height, of each subtree on level h-1, and if one is a mismatch it return false;, else it is true

Comment: sure, major issue with that is that you will end up with a o(n^2) solution (depth function is o(n) and is called for each of the n nodes), which is pretty horrible given that the solution i posted is o(n). if you will think that going for a o(n^2) solution makes sense even thought there is a o(n) solution because **you cant have more than 1 parameter in a helper**, sure! as asinine as i find that choice, its your solution, so you decide. :)

Comment: I'd like to use yours, but I am not actually allowed to. That is why I am using O(n^2)

Comment: @sbowde4 It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved, or close to a resolution. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."

Comment: I will once I completely finish the method